# How launch external executable in uwp app

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, uwp, hololens

Here my problem, i create a couple mini game for windows 10 (PC, phone, Hololens UWP, ...), but now i would like to make a launcher to gather all my games, like steam (for example).
But, according to Microsoft, it's impossible to launch a .exe or even .msi from UWP app -> ("This API also imposes several restrictions on what types of files it can launch. Many file types that contain executable code, for example .exe, .msi, and .js files, are blocked from launching. This restriction protects users from potentially malicious files that could modify the system.
")

And now i search a solution, maybe with the Full​Trust​Process​Launcher Class but i dont know how its works : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher#Windows_ApplicationModel_FullTrustProcessLauncher_LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync_System_String_

if you have an idea, a solution or even an exemple, I will be thankfull

Best regards

PS: sorry for the bad english, i'm french ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by supporting a custom protocol in your games. Then your launcher app can launch them via that protocol by using the LaunchUriAsync API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that is not going to work.

"Full​Trust​Process​Launcher Class
Activate the full-trust Win32 component of an application from a Universal Windows app component **in the same application package.**"

In other words this is to run a Win32 component of the current application.

Since Microsoft wants UWP to be more secure, your best option is probably to bundle your games together in one bigger application.  Have the start page / form be a menu of the games, then switch to another form for each game.

Name your classes, forms, resources carefully so you know what game they are for -- ChessMain, ChessForm, chess_logo.jpg;  CheckersMain, CheckersForm, CheckersPlayerTurn.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack way that may help to launch the exe in uwp.

If you want to use the win32 dll that in other directory,please get the LoadLibrary that can use it.

You can use

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info = {};  
if (VirtualQuery(VirtualQuery, &info, sizeof(info)))  
{
    auto kernelAddr = (HMODULE)info.AllocationBase;
    auto loadlibraryPtr = GetProcAddress(kernelAddr, "LoadLibraryExW");
    // load your library here ...
}
```

to get the loadlibrary and use to loadlibrary the dll.

See https://hjc.im/3-ways-to-bypass-wack/

Ms use the PE and P/Invoke to judge whether uwp use the not allowed dll.

So you can use the loadlibrary to load it.

You can launch the exe by win32.

But it may work today but it might break tomorrow.

Comment: @NabilABBACH I dont sure.